# How do you stop a broadcast intent?

Tags: android, broadcast

What is the code to stop or finish broadcast intent? I want to stop the reciever when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't stop a BroadcastReceiver.. you may try using a Service instead.

> public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
>
> Since: API Level 1
> This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast. During
> this time you can use the other methods on BroadcastReceiver to view/modify the current
> result values. The function is normally called within the main thread of its process, so
> **you should never perform long-running operations** in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that
> the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be
> killed). You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive().

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)